# Shared Projects, Multiple Solutions, Same Git Repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I have a single Git repository with about 5 solutions (.sln). Some of these solutions reference the same projects (.csproj). For example:

Solution 1

----Project A

----Project B

----Project C

Solution 2

----Project B

----Project C

The problem here is that depending on the solution that is currently opened in Visual Studio IDE, Project B is not marked as "Source Controlled". If I make a change on the project, no changes are tracked by Git.

Why this is happening? How can I fix that?

Comment: Does Project B created under solution 1? How did you add project B to solution 2? If project B under Solution 1 is managed in git repo, then what you changed for project B should be tracked by git.

Comment: We don´t know originally where projects where created. Maybe in the past Project B had its own solution.
The case now is that both Solution contain Project B. They are added by right-clicking on the solution then Add->Existing Project.
All projects and solutions are under the same git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the **Project B is not managed in your git repo**.

You can double check by find the directory where the project B located. Such as in your Solution 2 in Solution Explorer -> right click project B -> Open folder in File Explorer. Then you will find the path where project B located.  The directory is mainly different from where the local git repo located.

In order to **add project B in source control**, you should copy project B under the local git repo. Remove the old project B from different solutions (since the project you added for the solution id not managed in git),  then re-add the project B (which under your local git repo) to different solutions as you need.

Now the project B should managed in your git repo. After making changes for project B, VS will show the changes for you to commit.

Comment: Hi @Marina All project folders are on the same level. The solution files are inside some of these projects. Apparently I managed to fix this by simply removing the project from solution and adding it back again. It seems the solution now is referring projects with a different path structure.

Comment: The key is to put other projects next to `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` files.